# How to do I code for ANOVA repeated measures testing using numpy pandas statsmodels?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statistics, anova

I want to know how to conduct ANOVA repeated measures testing using the numpy pandas statsmodels library. My dataset contains information about depression scores pre-treatment, post-treatment, and follow-up after 6 months:

[Dataset screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovo4H.png)

Here are my null and research hypotheses:

H0 = Depression scores remain the same or have decreased after treatment over time.

H1 = Depression scores have increased after treatment over time.

I tried using the AnovaRM function, but it is giving me an error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

[What I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56aFC.png)

Here is the error I am getting:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp7pP.png)

I am a beginner at coding so I am quite confused! Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: instead of screenshots, try creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you can post

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.